# Touch image in navigation bar for redirecting another view

Tags: swift, swift2

I didnt see the image in navigation bar so how can i give event touch inside for that image ? Need help !

This is my code . Remember the image have not in the view.

[image]

Detail more for my issue is notification(the bell)

Comment: please post your code in the content without picture ,it should be more easy to assist handle your question

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this helps.

```
let img = UIImage(named: "icon.png");
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,(statImg?.size.width)!,(statImg?.size.height)!));
btn.setBackgroundImage(statImg, forState: .Normal);
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourController.yourMethod), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside);

let barBtn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: btn);
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

Comment: it seems is not my issue :( ! the image in the navigation bar and i can not set event for the bell .

Comment: How do you set the selector?

Comment: Yes i setted the selector by different func ,it is fine . I have solved it ! Thank mates :)